# Remove cronjobs from old module - Magento 2

Tags: magento2, cron, crontab, cronjobs

We had a module that created 3 specific cronjobs. This module was located in the app/code folder and we recently removed the entire module by removing the folder and then run the upgrade command.

But now when we check `magerun2 sys:cron:list` we still see that these 3 cronjobs exist. They still run, but will not succeed because the module is removed.

How can we also remove those 3 cronjobs?

Comment: 1. Do you have any extensions for manage cron? 2. Did you flush config cache? 3. Did you try to find this code in exists extensions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you may want to take a look at your redis cache? If the folder has gone, these crons are either on the database

```
select * from cron_schedule where job_code='';
```

or also in the cache particularly if you use redis.

Comment: It was indeed the redis cache, thanks Herve!

Comment: great to hear, thanks for the follow up

Answer (score 0):

The normal way of creating a cron job in Magento is by defining it in your module's `crontab.xml` file. There are however 2 config readers, the standard one for XML but also one to read the config from the DB.

My guess is perhaps the module created the jobs programmatically by writing them into the DB.

Run the following SQL:

```
SELECT * FROM `core_config_data` WHERE `path` LIKE 'system/crontab/%'
```

This should show any that were created using the DB method.